# Function-style macros vs PROC FCMP functions

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am considering replacing a lot of function-style macros with FCMP equivalents.  Before I go through this process I was wondering what limitations FCMP has compared to function style macros?  Has anyone else been through this process and are there any reasons why I would *not* want to do this?

My reasons for wanting to do this is to make code easier to read and maintain, and less error-prone.  I believe that FCMP functions are easier to read than macro code for most SAS programmers.

Comment: This is a very broad question and mostly likely not appropriate for StackOverflow.  It is a very good topic for discussion.  Have you considered a listserve like the sasconsulting Google Group?

Comment: And if you do start the discussion elsewhere, please drop a comment with a link. This would be a good topic for a user group paper.

Comment: Here is link to question I created on SAS Communiteis Forum. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Function-style-macros-vs-proc-fcmp-functions/m-p/244008

Comment: This article does a good job of explaining something... http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2013/BON-02.pdf